# RDBMS first normal from with json fields

Tags: json, postgresql, rdbms

Should usage of postgresql json field be considered as breaking first normal form?

Where this question came from. I have table of about 1,000,000 books. Each book could have several genres (total about 40 distinct genres).

I have found that classic relation N to M from book to genre tables almost useless because of low cardinality in almost any genre related it leads to full scan of result subset.

I tend to use json field, it would increase table size but not much.

But I am curious - is this solution should be considered breaking 1NF?

Comment: If you have a performance problem with a specific query, please read: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: I did. Thank you. In case of specific problem I will ask specific question. This one sounds a bit different than "Help I a problem with some query"

Comment: What happens when you search genres after you merge them to your book table? will it be a table scan? the map table suppose to have two id integers only and should be much faster even for a table scan. You need proved sufficient gain on performance to adjust your de-normalization.

Comment: _is this solution should be considered breaking 1NF_: Yes, in the way that if that design wouldn't break 1NF, nothing would.